# sql result show in particular row

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(F_Exhibition_Name) AS F_Site_name,
  (SELECT
    SUM(F_Quantity)
  FROM T_assets
  WHERE T_assets.F_ref_code = T_Item_movement.ItemCode
  AND F_State = 'A')
  AS openingqty,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM T_Item_movement
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_L2Category
  ON T_L2Category.F_ItemCode = T_Item_movement.ItemCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Exhibition
  ON T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code = T_Item_movement.F_Site_Code
WHERE F_Cat_code = 'FN'
--AND F_Cat_code IN ('EC', 'EL', 'FL', 'FN', 'GR', 'MX', 'OT', 'SH')
AND F_L1Cat_code = 'TT'
AND itemcode = 'TT015-BLK'
AND CONVERT(varchar(10), F_datetime, 112) >= '20130915'
AND CONVERT(varchar(10), F_datetime, 112) <= '20150915'
AND F_Exhibition_Name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ItemCode,
         dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status,
         dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code,
         dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
```

i am getting out put like this:
[image]

I am getting gulf glass 2015 in two column. I want to get in column and show the result in same column only.

Expected output :

```
Gulf class 2015    6    5
ATM 2015           0     3
```

Comment: your unnamed columns need to be aggregated and grouped on F_Site_Name. the 2 rows must have different F_Status, F_Site_Code or F_Frm_Site_Code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    SELECT F_Site_name, openingqty, 
    SUM(col1) AS col1, SUM(col2) AS col2
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
      MIN(F_Exhibition_Name) AS F_Site_name,
      (SELECT
        SUM(F_Quantity)
      FROM T_assets
      WHERE T_assets.F_ref_code = T_Item_movement.ItemCode
      AND F_State = 'A')
      AS openingqty,
      CASE
        WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND
          dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
        ELSE 0
      END AS col1,
      CASE
        WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND
          dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
        ELSE 0
      END AS col2
    FROM T_Item_movement
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T_L2Category
      ON T_L2Category.F_ItemCode = T_Item_movement.ItemCode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Exhibition
      ON T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code = T_Item_movement.F_Site_Code
    WHERE F_Cat_code = 'FN'
    --AND F_Cat_code IN ('EC', 'EL', 'FL', 'FN', 'GR', 'MX', 'OT', 'SH')
    AND F_L1Cat_code = 'TT'
    AND itemcode = 'TT015-BLK'
    AND CONVERT(varchar(10), F_datetime, 112) >= '20130915'
    AND CONVERT(varchar(10), F_datetime, 112) <= '20150915'
    AND F_Exhibition_Name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ItemCode,
             dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status,
             dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code,
             dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
    ) AS t
GROUP BY F_Site_name, openingqty
```

Comment: sir this is working fine..i dont want column name? so how i will re write? what is the changes u made in my query?

Comment: without column names such as "col1", "col2". query will not work. Without column names u can't use your results in other queries or in application

Answer (score 0):

It's the `GROUP BY` columns that are causing it.

You could change your `CASE` Statement to `SUM` the result, and therefore remove some of the columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
...
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND ...
       THEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity
       ELSE 0
  END),

...

GROUP BY ItemCode
```